# Write extra spaces to html element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We have JavaScript that writes to the document title and attempts to pad it with extra spaces...

```
document.title = "My Title&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

But this gets translated to "My Title&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;"

Anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: I agree with SLaks, I see no reason why you should do this. If you just want to separate different elements of the title why not use `document.title="My Title - My Subtitle";` etc.

Answer (score 8):

`&nbsp;` is an [HTML entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2) that represents the character reference `&#160;` (see [list of entities in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)) that again represents the Unicode character U+00A0. Now [`document.title`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-18446827) is of the type [DOMString that is similar to CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-642250288) that’s value is not parsed. That means you cannot use HTML references for `document.title` as the value is not parsed as HTML.

Try Javascript’s Unicode escape sequences to denote these character like this:

```
document.title = "My Title\u00A0\u00A0"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, not only for the answer but for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `document.title` property is a normal string that is not HTML-encoded.
You should set it to `"My Title  "`.

However, the browser may strip the spaces itself; <strike>there is nothing you can do about that</strike>.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
const titleElement = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]
titleElement.innerHTML = '&#160;'
```

But as pointed out, spaces of all types are stripped.

But, if you add `&#6158;` (the MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR ) to the end, it will not strip out the previous spaces.

```
titleElement.innerHTML = '&#6158;&#160;'
```

At least in Chrome.